# Positional argument error when Converting Spark Dataframe to H2O dataframe

Tags: pyspark, h2o

I am trying to learn how to use PySpark and H20 and most of the concepts underneath are very new to me. I want to implement a random forest algorithm using H2O but I have a Spark dataframe to work with. I am using Google Colab Notebook. Below is how my spark dataframe and environment were set up:

```
# Install java
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null

# get spark
VERSION='3.2.2'
!wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-$VERSION/spark-$VERSION-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz

# decompress spark
!tar xf spark-$VERSION-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz

# install python package to help with system paths
!pip install -q findspark'''
# Let Colab know where the java and spark folders are

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = f"/content/spark-{VERSION}-bin-hadoop3.2"

#add pyspark to sys.path using findspark
import findspark
findspark.init()

# get a spark session
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Obtaining the data from Google cloud Storage buckets

```
! wget https://storage.googleapis.com/bdt-spark-store/internal_data.csv -O gcs_internal_data.csv

! wget https://storage.googleapis.com/bdt-spark-store/external_sources.csv -O gcs_external_sources.csv


#Reading into spark

df1 = spark.read.csv('/content/gcs_internal_data.csv', sep =',', inferSchema=True, 
header = True)


df2 = spark.read.csv('/content/gcs_external_sources.csv', sep =',', inferSchema=True, 
header = True)

joinedDF = df1.join(df2, df1.SK_ID_CURR == df2.SK_ID_CURR)
```

filtering the data

```
df_spk = joinedDF.select('EXT_SOURCE_1', 'EXT_SOURCE_2', 'EXT_SOURCE_3',
                          'DAYS_BIRTH', 'DAYS_EMPLOYED', 'NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE',
                           'DAYS_ID_PUBLISH', 'CODE_GENDER', 'AMT_ANNUITY',
                           'DAYS_REGISTRATION', 'AMT_GOODS_PRICE', 'AMT_CREDIT',
                           'ORGANIZATION_TYPE', 'DAYS_LAST_PHONE_CHANGE',
                            'NAME_INCOME_TYPE', 'AMT_INCOME_TOTAL', 'OWN_CAR_AGE', 
                            'TARGET')
```

Convert spark dataframe to H2O frame

```
! apt-get install default-jre
! java -version 
! pip install h2o_pysparkling_3.2


import pysparkling
 
from pysparkling import *
hc= pysparkling.context.H2OContext(sc)
```

this is the error I get

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-507df42899af> in <module>
----> 1 hc= pysparkling.context.H2OContext(sc)

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

and if I run:

```
h2oFrame = hc.asH2OFrame(df_spk)
```

I get the error:

```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
><ipython-input-49-d563908a6983> in <module>
>----> 1 h2oFrame = hc.asH2OFrame(df_spk)

>/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ai/h2o/sparkling/H2OContext.py in 
asH2OFrame(self, >sparkFrame, h2oFrameName, fullCols)
>    199         assert_is_type(sparkFrame, DataFrame, RDD)
>    200 
>--> 201         df = H2OContext.__prepareSparkDataForConversion(self._jvm, sparkFrame)
>    202         if h2oFrameName is None:
>    203             key = self._jhc.asH2OFrame(df._jdf).frameId()
>
>AttributeError: 'H2OContext' object has no attribute '_jvm
```